# PETSC: Solving a simpler PDE results in error while solving the original equation works in snes/tutorials/ex13.c

Tags: finite-element, pde, petsc

In `snes/tutorials/ex13.c`,
there is a function `SetupPrimalProblem()`,
which sets up the $f_0$ and $f_1$ in `PetscDSSetResidual()`
as described in [here](https://petsc.org/release/manualpages/DT/PetscDSSetResidual/#petscdssetresidual),
and also the boundary conditions using the exact solution `trig_inhomogeneous_u()`.

Now, I am trying to modify $f_0$, $f_1$, and the boundary conditions in order to solve the 2D equation
$$
u+\Delta u=f,
$$
where $f(x,y)=x$ and the boundary conditions are determined by the exact solution $u(x,y)=x$ on $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2$.

In order to do this, I defined the following point-wise functions:

```
static void f00(PetscInt dim, PetscInt Nf, PetscInt NfAux, const PetscInt uOff[], const PetscInt uOff_x[], const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar u_t[], const PetscScalar u_x[], const PetscInt aOff[], const PetscInt aOff_x[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar a_t[], const PetscScalar a_x[], PetscReal t, const PetscReal x[], PetscInt numConstants, const PetscScalar constants[], PetscScalar f0[])
{
  f0[0] -= u[0];
  f0[0] += x[0];
}

static void f11(PetscInt dim, PetscInt Nf, PetscInt NfAux, const PetscInt uOff[], const PetscInt uOff_x[], const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar u_t[], const PetscScalar u_x[], const PetscInt aOff[], const PetscInt aOff_x[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar a_t[], const PetscScalar a_x[], PetscReal t, const PetscReal x[], PetscInt numConstants, const PetscScalar constants[], PetscScalar f1[])
{
  PetscInt d;
  for (d = 0; d < dim; ++d)
  {
    f1[d] = u_x[d];
  }
}

static void u_exact(PetscInt dim, PetscReal time, const PetscReal x[], PetscInt Nc, PetscScalar *u, void *ctx)
{
  *u = 0.0;
  *u += x[0];
  return PETSC_SUCCESS;
}
```

I then replaced the `f0`,
`f1_u`
and `ex`
in `SetupPrimalProblem()`
by the corresponding
`f00`,
`f11`,
and `u_exact`
.

However, I got the following error message:

```
[0]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message --------------------------------------------------------------
[0]PETSC ERROR:  
[0]PETSC ERROR: See https://petsc.org/release/faq/ for trouble shooting.
[0]PETSC ERROR: Petsc Release Version 3.19.3, unknown 
[0]PETSC ERROR: ./ex13 on a arch-linux-c-debug named LAPTOP by user Tue Jul 11 04:06:13 2023
[0]PETSC ERROR: Configure options --COPTFLAGS=-O3 --CXXOPTFLAGS=-O3 --FOPTFLAGS=-O3 --with-shared-libraries --with-cxx-dialect=C++11 --with-make-np=8 --download-hdf5=yes --download-mumps=yes --download-parmetis=yes --download-metis=yes --download-superlu=yes --download-hypre=yes --download-superlu_dist=yes --download-scalapack=yes --download-triangle=yes
[0]PETSC ERROR: #1 DMProjectPoint_Func_Private() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/impls/plex/plexproject.c:128
[0]PETSC ERROR: #2 DMProjectPoint_Private() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/impls/plex/plexproject.c:395
[0]PETSC ERROR: #3 DMProjectLocal_Generic_Plex() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/impls/plex/plexproject.c:852
[0]PETSC ERROR: #4 DMProjectFunctionLabelLocal_Plex() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/impls/plex/plexproject.c:921
[0]PETSC ERROR: #5 DMProjectFunctionLabelLocal() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/interface/dm.c:8071
[0]PETSC ERROR: #6 DMPlexInsertBoundaryValuesEssential() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/impls/plex/plexfem.c:795
[0]PETSC ERROR: #7 DMPlexInsertBoundaryValues_Plex() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/impls/plex/plexfem.c:1046
[0]PETSC ERROR: #8 DMPlexInsertBoundaryValues() at /home/user/petsc/src/dm/impls/plex/plexfem.c:1154
[0]PETSC ERROR: #9 DMPlexSNESComputeBoundaryFEM() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/utils/dmplexsnes.c:1372
[0]PETSC ERROR: #10 SNESComputeFunction_DMLocal() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/utils/dmlocalsnes.c:63
[0]PETSC ERROR: #11 SNESComputeFunction() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/interface/snes.c:2389
[0]PETSC ERROR: #12 SNESSolve_NEWTONLS() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/impls/ls/ls.c:172
[0]PETSC ERROR: #13 SNESSolve() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/interface/snes.c:4644
[0]PETSC ERROR: #14 PetscConvEstGetConvRateSNES_Private() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/utils/convest.c:369
[0]PETSC ERROR: #15 PetscConvEstGetConvRate() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/utils/convest.c:468
[0]PETSC ERROR: #16 SNESSolve() at /home/user/petsc/src/snes/interface/snes.c:4561
[0]PETSC ERROR: #17 main() at ex13.c:431
[0]PETSC ERROR: Reached the main program with an out-of-range error code 584475600. This should never happen
[0]PETSC ERROR: PETSc Option Table entries:
[0]PETSC ERROR: -convest_num_refine 2 (source: command line)
[0]PETSC ERROR: -potential_petscspace_degree 1 (source: command line)
[0]PETSC ERROR: -snes_convergence_estimate (source: command line)
[0]PETSC ERROR: -snes_monitor (source: command line)
[0]PETSC ERROR: ----------------End of Error Message -------send entire error message to petsc-maint@mcs.anl.gov----------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI_COMM_SELF
with errorcode 584475600.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no idea why the program solves the original, more complicated, equation successfully while not being able to solve a simpler one.
Any help or reference would be much appreciated.

---

The original equation and solution seem to be:
$$
\Delta u = f
$$
where $f(x,y)= -4\pi^2(\sin(2\pi x)+\sin(2\pi y))$
with $u(x,y)=\sin(2\pi x)+\sin(2\pi y)$ using Dirichlet's boundary conditions.

Comment: I don't see where in the part of the snippets you shared, but the error looks to me to indicate a out of bounds error. I would compile with `-fsanitize=address` just to better locate where it actually occurs.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Appreciate it. I actually solved the problem simply by changing the return type of ```u_exact()``` from ```void``` to ```PetscErrorCode```. No idea why the original example works with no error, and no idea why my code even compiles successfully :) Maybe a bug?